# How to get the total execution time of a previously executed shell script in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to know that how can I get the total execution time of a shell script that has already completed execution in the past? I wanted to check that how much time it took and align a few additional processes after it.

P.S I can't run it again, it is auto-scheduled.

Comment: If it's auto-scheduled, the start time is well-defined. Don't you have a way to see when it has finished in some kind of "Linux task scheduler"?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is an option for you to use `zsh` instead of `bash`? In `zsh` you can set an environment variable `REPORTTIME` to a number of seconds. If the total execution time of any command exceeds this time, the shell will print the duration in the end.

Example:

```
export REPORTTIME=8
```

Comment: As I mentioned before, I can't change or rerun the query. It's auto scheduled and I need to know the last total execution time of the query.

Comment: Then why not put `time` in front of the scheduled command, so that the time is always printed?